# accessing 500 text file in 1 folder and spleting them according to certain delimeters

Tags: c#, winforms, text-files

So, I've got 500 .txt files contain **a lot** of words
and I want to access those 500 files and store each word in it into a dictionary (the word is separated by space, "/" , "," , ".", etc...)
any ideas how can I work this out in C#?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would consider using multiple threads and a ConcurrentDictionary (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Read these about [Reading Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-from-a-text-file), [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx), [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx), [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx). I think you be able to solve your problem.

Comment: read them in one by one - if this proofs as too long, change it to multi threaded or async await. get startet - youll finish it sooner that way. If you handle 500 files with only some MB each it will be fast enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Retrieve all the TXT files from the target folder...
String[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\MyPath\","*.txt");

// Initialize a new data container in the form of a Dictionary...
Dictionary<String, String[]> data = new Dictionary<String, String[]>(filePaths.Length);

// Parse all the TXT files into the Dictionary...
foreach (String filePath in filePaths)
{
    String fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
    String fileContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    String[] words = fileContent.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    data.Add(fileName, words);
}
```

After a try, if you feel that the performance is not brilliant, you can switch to a multithreading approach as different users already suggested.